# Issues with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

i'm new to selenium webdriver. Right now i'm facing with some issue where eclipse is not throwing any exception for some set of code & it keeps waiting forever after reaching that code line.It is happening mostly, but same set of code if i try to execute after sometime again it works fine. Can somebody help me with this?

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement element=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By.cssSelector("#menu1"))));
            element.click();
```

Comment: I am also new to Selenium. Maybe you need Thread.sleep(5000); such a waiting time. But it is just an idea.

Comment: This may be due to your are using executing the driver and you are closing the browser of previous executions. It occupy your memory. Please make sure, the browser which was opened by previous execution is closed before executing a script. If more opened browser of previous execution, it hinder the performance of the system.

Comment: @shravan This may happen due to various reasons and one of them can be the wrong selection of `ExpectedConditions`. Can you show your work and the relevant HTML DOM please? Thanks

Comment: <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
   <span class="caret"></span></button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>